# How to find a matrix D such that B + D is a singular matrix.

Tags: matrices

B=$\begin{pmatrix} e & 10 \\ 2 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$

How to  find a matrix D such that B + D is a singular matrix.

Can anyone please show this answer

Comment: $-B$ will probably do.

Comment: Can you show how to solve this problem

Comment: It seems that you have little understanding of singularity. Please write down the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $B+D$ to be singular at at least one of the rows or columns should be zero.You can also have singular matrix with non zero columns or rows but finding them requires you brute force it

So you can have $D = \begin{pmatrix}a&&-10\\b&&-8\end{pmatrix}$

$D = \begin{pmatrix}-e&&-10\\b&&a\end{pmatrix}$

$D =\begin{pmatrix}-e&&a\\-2&&b\end{pmatrix}$

$D = \begin{pmatrix} a&&b\\-2&&-8\end{pmatrix}$

$D = -B$

for any real number $a , b$

Comment: Can you explain how did you get the first step of D=

Comment: Please explain in detail, I did not understand

Comment: You have get at least one column  or row zero so you make the other matrix have the same elements with a negative sign.So adding will give you 0